# SO API: How to get a user's reputation rank/position?

Tags: api, ranking, shared-libraries

Having earned the "[Tumbleweed](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed)" badge for [this](https://stackapps.com/questions/2563/how-to-get-a-users-reputation-ranking-position) question, I thought I'd re-post here and put it to a larger audience:

Using the SO API request `http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/[userId]`, I can get a user's current reputation score with no problems. What I'd like to know is where the user's rank in the set of all the StackOverflow users is - for example, "the top 10%", or alternatively "the position 18,415 out of 520,546". Ideally, I'd like to be able to get this for various time periods: for all the time, the last month, the last year.

Profile pages now have this info for the last week, is it possible to get this data and for other periods from the API?

Comment: You should try posting this [on the meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), maybe it would get more views and get an answer?